# How to use scanf to read each line of a file with space?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

So I'm trying to write a c program that can read each line of a file pass to it by command line and print out each line. My code look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

        char num[20];
        for (;;){
                if((scanf("%[^\n]s", num)) != 1){
                        break;
                }
                printf("%s\n", num);
        }
}
```

The unix command line is: ./printeachline < num.txt

the num.txt includes these lines:

```
01 0111111119
111122222228
123400000000
1234kk444k44
oooo11111111
o dk39754i2oo
002711111116
124145245 246623
0027111111167
888888888888
100900000011
```

What I'm expecting to print out is every line in num.txt, However when I enter the command only the first line is printed, that is 01 0111111119. How could I fix this????

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your question is not how to use `scanf()` to solve your problem, but rather use `fgets()` instead. `scanf()` is known to be error-prone, may cause buffer overflow, etc. `fgets()` is the function that's designed to be used to process each line:

```
while (fgets(num, sizeof num, fp) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s", num);
}
```

`fp` is the `FILE *` pointer for `num.txt`.

Comment: @TomášZato Use `sscanf` to read the integers from the string that `fgets` gets.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fgets()` or if you are using GNU C then you can use `getline()` to read the input line by line. Or you can add a `getchar()` in loop in your program then the program will work. It reads the newline character left by `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

char num[20];
for (;;){
if((scanf("%[^\n]s", num)) != 1){
break;
}
printf("%s\n", num);
getchar();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf leaves the newline at the end of the line, so the next scanf will fail. Add a getchar() to read and throw away the newline character.

But, as others have said, use fgets instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from file then better use file operations. You can refer to this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling/